# Amazon AWS IVS Player got stuck on loading state while playing LIVE video content

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, video-player, live-video, amazon-ivs

I'm using Amazon IVS Player & playing LIVE Content.

In case of Playing Live video, It got stuck after this log.

```
playhead 2.1333 max buffer 2.9999999 max played 2.99999
```

And the it goes on loading state.

I Also checked the browser network tab, There it only downloading manifest file.. not able download *.ts files

Can someone help me in this... Unable to understand the behaviour.

Amazon IVS Player Version: v1.19.0

Next.JS Version: v13.1.6

Comment: did you figure this one out? I also face this issue and not sure how to solve it

Comment: Not able to understand actual error. but it eventually fixed